# Is there any way to send my app to others for downloading the apk file without deploying it in store?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, deployment

I am trying to send my created app to testers  and supervisors.  I can't get ahold of their phones to run the app from my laptop. Is there anyway i can send them the app to download without deploying to the store.

I am using Android studio for the code, and the app is for android.

Answer (score 2):

you can upload your apk file to your  **Google Drive**  and share the app link with others , to whom you wish to share and test the code.

[link :](https://www.google.com/drive/)

it is the most simplest way for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Build then select build Apks(s)

[image]

2. Once done, Click locate on the popup that appears on the bottom right, or go to the event log at the bottom right to see the dialog if the build is successful

[image]

3. Go to [File Uploader](https://nofile.io/) and upload the app_debug
4. Send the link to your friends and let them download and install the app

Answer (score 0):

You can just mail them the APK file.  Or you can set up a beta or alpha channel in the Play Store, and make them alpha/beta testers in a closed alpha/beta.